# Workaround for: Use of undeclared identifier '_cmd'

Tags: objective-c, c, logging, macros, nsstring

I have a special `NSLog` method swizzle that prints the current method as part of the log statement.

For Objective-C methods, I have a macro that uses: `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)`

For non Objective-C methods, I have a second macro that uses `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` because `_cmd` is not defined.

I am now trying to use the same macro for both, so I am trying to test if it is defined and thought I could do so like this:

```
NSString *command = (&_cmd != nil ? NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) : [NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])
```

but I am still getting some `Use of undeclared identifier '_cmd'` errors when the macro is used in non Objective-C methods. How can I do a runtime test do determine if `_cmd` is defined or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test at runtime whether `_cmd` is defined.

The `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro is defined in Objective-C methods.  Just use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` everywhere and don't try to use `_cmd`.

Example:

```
- (IBAction)mapWasTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
2012-12-01 11:45:30.036 TestApp[92581:c07] -[MainViewController mapWasTapped:]
```

Comment: The problem is that I am looking for just the method name, not the class name. I could try some parsing, but can't be sure that __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ will return something that looks the same every time

Comment: If `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` starts with a `-` or `+`, strip everything up to a space and strip the trailing `]`.

Comment: I ended up using a NSScanner to grab everything after "[", then between " " and "]" because methods called from blocks have a __block_invoke_0 after the "]"